# Apply" Github automated security fixes" to a different branch?

Tags: github

Github recently released [automated security fixes](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-automated-security-fixes). However, they always attempt to merge fixes to `master`, we have a strict policy of only merging to `master` after QA testing, so instead would rather it merges to `develop`. So currently I need to manually create the diffs and PR's manually.

Is there anyway to target `develop` instead?